# From IOS native app JavaScript function calling

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, iphone, webview

My requirement is very clear from IOS native app wants to call remote server javascript function the case study is like:

In Objective-C, I am developing UI with two textfield, one button, one label.
From two textfield I am passing two integers ex: 5, 7 and expecting on button click ans 12 will display on label.

The Some will perform on server using javascript:
A javascript file kept on remote web server ex: http://72.x.x.x/demo/mylib.js

Javascript having following code:

```
function sum(x,y) {
 var z = parseInt(x)+parseInt(y);
 return z;
}
```

What would be a objective-c code?

Answer (score 0):

Why not expose the server api through http?

http://72.x.x.x/demo/sum?x=5&y=7

In client, you can use http client get json response